# Nodemailer Attachments doesn't work

Tags: node.js, express

I'm trying to send an attachment with email using Nodemailer but I get "Unexpected identifier" error for attachments. Seems nodejs doesn't recognize the "attachments". Is there anything else i have to install from npm other than nodemaler and path
below is the email route:

```
app.post("/send", function(req,res){

var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
 service: 'gmail',
 auth: {
        user: 'my gamil',
        pass: 'my gmail password'
    }
});


const mailOptions = {
  from: req.body.fr, // sender address
  to: req.body.to, // list of receivers
  bcc: req.body.fr,
  subject: req.body.subject, // Subject line
  html: '<h4>Dear ' + req.body.contname+ '</h4>' + '<p>'+ req.body.message + '</p>' + '<p>Kind Regards</p>' + req.body.user// html body
  attachments: [  
        {   
          filePath: req.body.myFile,
        },
        {   
          filename: req.body.myFile,
        },   
    ],
};

    transporter.sendMail(mailOptions, (error, info) => {
    if (error) {
        return console.log(error);
    }
    console.log('Message sent: %s', info.messageId);
    console.log('Preview URL: %s', nodemailer.getTestMessageUrl(info));


   });
 });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're getting, this:

```
        attachments: [{
        ^^^^^^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
```

It is because you're missing a comma at the end of `html` property.

```
const mailOptions = {
    from: req.body.fr, // sender address
    to: req.body.to, // list of receivers
    bcc: req.body.fr,
    subject: req.body.subject, // Subject line
    // Comma missing at the end of html =>
    html: '<h4>Dear ' + req.body.contname + '</h4>' + '<p>' + req.body.message + '</p>' + '<p>Kind Regards</p>' + req.body.user, // Comma missing here
    attachments: [{
        filePath: req.body.myFile
    } {
        filename: req.body.myFile
    }]
};
```

It has **nothing** to do with nodemailer attachments not working. Your code has syntax errors.

Comment: Remember, `SyntaxError` is the key :)

Comment: Now I can send the attachment but when I get the email the attachment is not readable no matter if it’s jpg or pdf, do you know the problem?

Comment: Yeah, you're not sending an actual file, what does: `console.log(req.body.myFile)` prints? a filename?

Comment: it prints filename.pdf. i don't know if it's an actual file or just a file name!!

Comment: It doesn't point, it's a string containing a filename, that's why it isn't working. What are you using to upload files? multer?

Comment: just a built-in js...<input name="myFile" type="file">

Comment: Unless you want only the filename, you should check https://www.npmjs.com/package/multer for handling the upload. Once you have an actual file, you won't have issues sending the attachment.

Comment: Thanks. I will try multer. the myFile above was actually a javascript function for uplaoding

Comment: Yes, but the problem is, while the upload may reach the server, you're not doing anything with it, so you can't use it on your middlewares, unless you handle that upload, multer will do it for you.

Comment: is it like uploading and saving the file in a folder on server then call the path of that file in the attachments array?

Comment: Exactly, then you pass the path to `nodemailer` attachment path, and you're done

Comment: Let me know :)!

Comment: 'm struggling with multer, i think i have to ask another question in stack, if i put the question link here, will you answer?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50403834/how-to-save-a-file-on-server-using-multer